# "Error: FFMPEG not found" but FFMPEG should be installed - Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord

So I've been working on a Discord Music bot and I need FFMPEG, I just cant seem to find a working build.

I already tried to install it via npm, choco, git and I used the installer from ffmpeg's website. None of these worked.

This is my Error:

```
Error: FFMPEG not found
    at Function.selectFfmpegCommand (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\Ffmpeg.js:46:13)
    at new FfmpegTranscoder (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\Ffmpeg.js:7:37)
    at new MediaTranscoder (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\MediaTranscoder.js:10:19)
    at new Prism (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\prism-media\src\Prism.js:5:23)
    at new VoiceConnection (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:46:18)
    at Promise (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js:63:22)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ClientVoiceManager.joinChannel (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js:45:12)
    at VoiceChannel.join (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\VoiceChannel.js:130:30)
    at Client.bot.on (C:\Users\MauSc\Desktop\CrafterMusic - JS\index.js:50:76)
```

Edit: I should probably point out that Im an absolute beginner and have difficulties finding errors on my own.

Comment: you say *ffmpeg should be installed* ... should be? well, did you?

Comment: well I did install it via npm, choco and git. So it technically *should* be installed, right?

Comment: open command prompt in windows - type "ffmpeg" and enter - do you get ffmpeg output or an error? (you can't install ffmpeg via npm or git as far as I know - not sure about choco, but choco is hit and miss in my experience, and more miss than hit) - I've always installed ffmpeg in windows using an installer from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Thats my output: https://pastebin.com/RdKrqPiK, I forgot that I used the installer too, I copied the ffmpeg folder to node_modules. Im not sure if thats right.

Comment: this is the ffmpeg tutorial I followed: https://youtu.be/f_OOhBniSu8

Comment: make sure your windows PATH points to where you installed ffmpeg - that's the easiest way to make it work - oh, wait, you DO have ffmpeg in the PATH, the pastebin shows you do have ffmpeg

Comment: Well i got this in the Path https://imgur.com/a/P55Nrg9

Comment: see how I recognised it must be in the PATH already - so, that's not the problem

Comment: any other idea what could cause the error?

Comment: Alright I fixed it with this tutorial: https://youtu.be/prSOkqHXwg0 . It basically sets the PATH via console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial helped me https://youtu.be/prSOkqHXwg0

It basically sets the PATH via console, which ended up working for me.